# fork() and pipe() in C goes wrong

Tags: c, pipe, fork

I am learning about fork and pipe but have a problem with the following: My aim was to build a program with 3 processes and I did that but my question is: **Why does `printf("Sum of first half: %d\n", sum);` get executed twice?**

I checked the code for any logical errors that I made but couldn't find anything.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);
    int sum;

    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);

    int id = fork();

    if (id == 0) // Child process
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size / 2; i++)
            sum = sum + arr[i];

        int j = fork();
        if (j == 0)
        {
            printf("Hello I'm the grandchild\n");
        }
    }

    else // Parent process
    {
        for (int i = size / 2; i < size; i++)
            sum = sum + arr[i];
    }

    if (id == 0) // Child process writing to the pipe
    {
        close(fd[0]);
        write(fd[1], &sum, sizeof(sum));
        close(fd[0]);
        printf("Sum of first half: %d\n", sum);
    }

    else // Parent process reading from the pipe
    {
        int x;
        close(fd[1]);
        read(fd[0], &x, sizeof(sum));
        close(fd[1]);
        printf("Sum of second half: %d\n", sum);
        printf("Total sum: %d\n", x + sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have the child and the grandchild. They both have `id == 0`.

Comment: yeah but they are different processes. the name of one is id other is j

Comment: The parent has `id = <child pid>` and `j` never exists. The child has `id = 0` and `j = <grandchild pid>`. The grandchild has `id = 0` and `j = 0`. At one point the child and grandchild were a single process with `id = 0`. You never do anything to change that, so the grandchild also has `id == 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code simplified:

```
int main()
{
    int id = fork();

    if (id == 0)
        fork();

    if (id == 0)
        printf("Sum of first half\n");
    else
        printf("Sum of second half\n");
}
```

And the explanation:

| code | Parent | Child | Granchild |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `fork()` | `fork` | N/A | N/A |
| `id` value | `id != 0` | `id==0` | N/A |
| `if (id == 0) fork()` | then not executed | `fork` | N/A |
| `id` value | `id != 0` | `id == 0` | `id == 0` |
| `if (id == 0) printf("sum first")` | then not executed | `printf` | `printf` |
| `else printf("sum second half")` | `printf` | else not executed | else not executed |

Comment: Wow, thank you I understand it.

Comment: It's appreciated